# liquibase preConditions when dbms type="mssql" with modifyDataType ignored with updateSQL

Tags: liquibase

i run simple changeSet to invoke alter table only on mssql 
like this :

```
<changeSet author="Foo" id="1">
        <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN" onSqlOutput="TEST">    
             <dbms type="mssql"/> 
        </preConditions>
        <modifyDataType tableName="SAMPLE" columnName="FOO" newDataType="nvarchar"/>            
    </changeSet>
```

what is happening is that the alter is created on all databases , what is wrong here?

In the log :

```
DEBUG 3/14/18 3:59 PM: liquibase: main.xml: ./schema/changelog111.xml::FOO : Projects::FOO: Running Changeset:./schema/changelog111.xml::FOO : Projects::FOO
DEBUG 3/14/18 3:59 PM: liquibase: main.xml: ./schema/changelog111.xml::FOO : Projects::FOO: Reading ChangeSet: ./schema/changelog111.xml::FOO : Projects::FOO
DEBUG 3/14/18 3:59 PM: liquibase: main.xml: ./schema/changelog111.xml::FOO : Projects::FOO: Executing Statement: liquibase.statement.core.ModifyDataTypeStatement@e98770d
INFO 3/14/18 3:59 PM: liquibase: main.xml: ./schema/changelog111.xml::FOO : Projects::FOO: SAMPLE.FOO datatype was changed to nvarchar
INFO 3/14/18 3:59 PM: liquibase: main.xml: ./schema/changelog111.xml::FOO : Projects::FOO: ChangeSet ./schema/changelog111.xml::FOO : Projects::FOO ran successfully in 2ms
```

No sign any where in the log for : preConditions

Comment: Can you run with --logLevel=DEBUG and attach the output running update against a couple of different database types? I don't know if that will show anything or not, but that would be my first step.

Comment: the log involve some private data but i will try to put here the relevant data when doing grep Foo

Comment: Just checking - are you running the `update` command or `updateSql`? 

Since there isn't anything in the logs, your best option might be to run liquibase with java debugging enabled and set a breakpoint in `DBMSPrecondition::check()` to see what is happening. The logic in that class is pretty simple.